# Combining serializers and sorting with filtering

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-serializer

I have a problem with the API JSON (serializers). I need to display only the last added price for a store and sort by lowest price for an article. There is no possibility to change the relationship in the database.

DB schema looks like.
[DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxKOj.png)

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data()

    def data(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

        
class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data()

    def data(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
    
class Price(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='prices')
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='shops') 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data()

    def data(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.name, self.date)
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import Article, Price, Shop
from rest_framework import serializers

class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ['name', 'date']

class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prices = PriceSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = ['name', 'prices']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        bdata = super().to_representation(instance)
        bdata ["prices"] = sorted(bdata["prices"], key=lambda x: x["date"], reverse=False)
        return bdata

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prices = PriceSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['name', 'prices']
```

views.py

```
from .models import Shop, Article, Price
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions, filters
from apitest.serializers import ArticleSerializer, PriceSerializer, ShopSerializer
#from rest_framework.response import Response
#from django.db.models import Prefetch

class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter]
    search_fields = ['^name']

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super(ArticleViewSet, self).filter_queryset(queryset)
        return queryset#.order_by('prices__date') #it's two times duplicate Articel records

class PriceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Price.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PriceSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

class ShopViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Shop.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShopSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

The result of my serializers looks like this.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Flashlight",
        "prices": [
            {
                "name": "15,99",
                "date": "2022-12-20"
            },
            {
                "name": "14,99",
                "date": "2022-12-22"
            },
            {
                "name": "11,99",
                "date": "2022-12-20"
            },
            {
                "name": "12,99",
                "date": "2022-12-22"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Cup",
        "prices": []
    }
]
```

I want to get exactly this result. I've been sitting on this for a week and I think I've tried all kinds of methods. Even view but there it has the same JSON article twice.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfDhi.png)

I tried everything from the web. It was not possible to get the required effect. The closest was using materialized view but in JSON I have repeated aricles for stores.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an ideal solution

Not exactly an ideal solution

```
from .models import Article, Price, Shop
from rest_framework import serializers

class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = ['id']

class LastPriceShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = ShopSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ['name', 'date', 'id']

class LastPriceInShopsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prices = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['name', 'prices']
        
#Unfortunately, stores must be hardcoded 
def get_prices2(self, instance):
    lastPriceShop1 = instance.prices2.filter(id=1).order_by('-date')[:1] #Shop1
    lastPriceShop2 = instance.prices2.filter(id=2).order_by('-date')[:1] #Shop2
    return LastPriceShopSerializer(lastPriceShop1, many=True).data, LastPriceShopSerializer(lastPriceShop2, many=True).data
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.